# How to know Dependencies of a module/library(for e.g. EclipseLink) when configuring it in JBoss 7.1

Tags: jboss

I am a newbie to JBoss 7. Forgive me if some of my questions below does not make sense…

My question is not necessarily related to 'EclipseLink' but I am giving reference of below example just to those who also like me did not know that we have to configure our modules/libraries first.

I was running an example which makes use of EclipseLink JPA EntityManager on JBoss 7.1. I have also configured the JTA datasource(mysql) with the help of link( https://zorq.net/b/2011/07/12/adding-a-mysql-datasource-to-jboss-as-7/ ). My persistence.xml looks like as below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="CustomerDetailsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/mysql_customerdb</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.springforbeginners.model.Customer</class>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I tried to run the example, I encounted with error(org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module org.eclipse.persistence is not found). I searched over the net and got the link (http://mpashworth.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/configuring-eclipselink-2-3-1-in-jboss-7-1/). The link says that we have to first configure EclipseLink as a module in JBoss 7.1. This involves listing dependencies of our module(in this case 'EclipseLink') in a module.xml file which looks like below stored at path(jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\org\eclipse\persistence\main)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Represents the EclipseLink 2.3.x module-->
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.eclipse.persistence">
 <resources>
 <resource-root path="eclipselink-2.3.0.jar"/>
 </resources>
 <dependencies>
  <module name="asm.asm"/>
  <module name="javax.api"/>
  <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
  <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
  <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
  <module name="org.antlr"/>
  <module name="org.apache.ant"/>
  <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
  <module name="org.dom4j"/>
  <module name="org.javassist"/>
  <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
 </dependencies>
</module>
```

We also have to place eclipselink-2.3.0 at the same path. I ran the example again to know that the error is resolved.

1. Why do we have to configure our libraries as modules?(as in earlier versions(JBoss 5.1) we just used to copy the jars in lib directory).
2. What I want to know is how do I know what are the dependencies that need to be listed in module.xml? The specified module.xml is working but I am still searching answer for my question? This is a general question and not just related to EclipseLink (as We may need to configure any other module in JBoss 7.1). Can anyone provide me a general pointer for knowing the dependencies for a module that we are going to configure with JBoss 7?

Thanking You in Advance.
Prakash

Comment: One more observation...

3. Not all library jars we have to add it as module, some jars still in WEB-INF\lib. So is there any rule which tells us that we have to add some jars as module while some other just need to keep in WEB-INF\lib?

Any help/pointer appreciated.

Thanks
Prakash

Comment: Got some meaningful information on JBoss site regarding modules and dependencies.  https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html

Comment: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364680/Understanding-J2EE-Application-Server-ClassLoading-Architectures

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Comment: http://vimeo.com/32211344